# How to configure Logstash IMAP plugin to fetch email from SMTP Server

Tags: smtp, logstash, imap, elastic-stack

I have a SMTP Server (using virtual SMTP server on windows server 2012), and a CentOS machine.
On CentOS machine, I installed ELK. Now I want to configure Logstash to get email from SMTP server by using IMAP plugin.

Please help me.

Thank you so much.

Comment: You should post this question on Server Fault

Comment: SMTP service in Windows servers is just to send emails out, if you need IMAP access to email accounts then you need to install a real mail server like MS Exchange, Postfix and Exim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below logstash configuration should work. Please change the settings and output plugins as per your need.

**logstash.conf**

```
input{
    imap{
        host => "SERVER_IP"
        user => "USERNAME"
        password => "************"
        port => PORT_NUMBER
        secure => true/false
        check_interval => INTERVAL_SECONDS
    }
}
output{
    stdout{
        codec => "json"
    }
}
```

Then start logstash using the below command

```
bin/logstash -f "logstash.conf"
```

This should check emails for every configured **check_interval** duration in seconds and trigger an event.

Comment: Where I can get user and password?

Comment: You've configured the SMTP server, right? Any email account on the SMTP server should work.

Comment: How to configure email account on SMTP server?
User and password are required?

Comment: @xuanhai266 - Please see if this post helps https://serverfault.com/questions/513887/smtp-set-up-where-do-i-configure-mail-accounts-on-windows-server-2008

Comment: BTW, SMTP is a mail sending protocol.  You cannot receive through it.

Comment: @Max - You are right when we see `SMTP` as a protocol. However, when we use the term `SMTP Server`, I think it's different. I might be wrong as well. The configuration I've provided uses `IMAP` protocol not `SMTP`.

Comment: Then it is /also/ an IMAP server.